# How to add centered text with gm for node (graphicsmagick/imagemagick)?

Tags: node.js, gm

This relates to the "gm" extension for node, http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html

I need to add some text centered around a bounding box (horizontally is enough). The function drawText() requires x,y coordinates, but there is no way to draw centered text.

I would otherwise need a function which can return the width of a text string in the font/size given, so I can calculate my starting x position in javascript, before calling drawText().

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `region` and `gravity` functions this way:

```
gm(filePath)
    .region(WIDTH, HEIGHT, X, Y)
    .gravity('Center')
    .fill(color)
    .fontSize(textFontSize)
    .font(font)
    .drawText(0, 0, 'This text will be centered inside the region')
```

Comment: Where do X and Y come from?

Comment: From your code. These describe the position and size of the bounding box of the text, which will be rendered in the center of it.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work for me at all. I was able to get the region working with a sepia filter, e.g. .region(WIDTH, HEIGHT, X, Y).sepia(), but not with text. Instead I simply did gm(filePath).drawText(0, 250, 'my text', 'North'), to get it centrally aligned.